# Find all entire functions with given conditions

Tags: complex-analysis

Find all entire functions f for which $|f(z)|≤ |z|^2$ if $|z|≤ 1$ and $|f(z)|≤ |z|^3$ if $|z|≥1$.
This is problem from previous prelim exam. I am working on it right now.I was thinking to show f to be bounded on complex plane and applying Liouville's I could not go ahead. Could you please help me on it?|f(z)||g(z)|

Comment: Do you mean $|z| \leq 1$ instead of $|z| = 1$? Note that it does not follow that $f$ is constant, because $f(x) = x^3$ satisfies your conditions. The same is true of $f(x) = x^2$.

Comment: @PhoemueX Yes it is |z|≤1 instead of |z|=1.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have a hard time showing $f$ is bounded, because it isn't necessarily! For instance, $f(z)=z$,  $f(z)=z^2$ and $f(z)=z^3$ satisfy your conditions, as **PhoemueX** points out.

Some things that may help:

1. Using the residue theorem along with the fact that $|f(z)|\leq |z|^3$, we can show that $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ for $n>3$, so $f$ is a polynomial of degree at most $3$.
2. Show that $f$ maps the unit disc to itself. Where can the zeroes of $f$ be?
3. For these kinds of problems, [Schwarz's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma) is often useful. I don't think you'll need it here, but since you're studying for a prelim exam, I figured I'd mention that it's a good thing to have in your toolbox.

Comment: $f(z) = z$ does not satisfy $|f(z)| \le |z|^2$ for $|z| \le 1$, for example at $z = 1/2$.

Comment: Dear @ronno: The question has since been edited. I'll leave it up to Ganna. Thanks though!